# pairwise combination of information from two embedded JSON arrays using terminal

Tags: json, jq

I have a json file like this:

```
{"offset":0,"results":[{"actividades/_text":["Ciencias Naturales Logro y Autoevaluación","Ciencias Naturales Seres Vivos - Objetos Inertes","Educación Artística Contenidos","Educación Religiosa Dibujo","Educación Religiosa Estructura 1 Periodo","Educación Religiosa Comunicado","Educación Religiosa Respuesta Eucaristía","Educación Religiosa Eucaristía","Expresión Corporal Estructura General","Expresión Corporal Vestuario de Ensayo","Ingles Recomendaciones Generales 2016","Ingles Temas Logros Indicadores Todos los Periodos","Ingles Rules and oral expressions to be used in the classroom","Lengua Castellana Estructura Curricular","Matemáticas Temas Logros 1 Periodo","Matemáticas Taller #1","Música Estructura 1 Periodo","Tecnología e Informática Support guide first term"],"actividades/_source":["/ArchivosCargados/2016/CUADRO-PRIMER-BIMESTRE-2016-PRIMERO.pdf","/ArchivosCargados/2016/Hojita-Seres-Vivos.pdf","/ArchivosCargados/2016/2016-CONTENIDOS-ARTES-PLASTICAS-PRIMARIA-J-T-12345.pdf","/ArchivosCargados/2016/PRIMERO-RELILGION.pdf","/ArchivosCargados/2016/Estructura-RELGION.pdf","/ArchivosCargados/2016/PRIMERO-RELIGION.pdf","/ArchivosCargados/2016/RESPUESTAS-EUCARISTIA.pdf","/ArchivosCargados/2016/respuestas-misa.pdf","/ArchivosCargados/2016/Estructura-general-grado-primero-2016.pdf","/ArchivosCargados/2016/VESTUARIO-CLASE-EXPRESION-CORPORAL-2016.pdf","/ArchivosCargados/2016/RECOMENDACIONES-GENERALES-2016.pdf","/ArchivosCargados/2016/TEMAS-LOGRO-INDICADORES-PERIODO.pdf","/ArchivosCargados/2016/ENGLISH-USED-IN-CLASS.pdf","/ArchivosCargados/2016/lc-1.pdf","/ArchivosCargados/2016/Temas-logros.pdf","/ArchivosCargados/2016/Taller1-16.pdf","/ArchivosCargados/2016/PROGRAMA-PLATAFORMA.pdf","/ArchivosCargados/2016/first-grade.pdf"],"actividades":["http://www.domain.com/ArchivosCargados/2016/CUADRO-PRIMER-BIMESTRE-2016-PRIMERO.pdf","http://www.domain.com/ArchivosCargados/2016/Hojita-Seres-Vivos.pdf","http://www.domain.com/ArchivosCargados/2016/2016-CONTENIDOS-ARTES-PLASTICAS-PRIMARIA-J-T-12345.pdf","http://www.domain.com/ArchivosCargados/2016/PRIMERO-RELILGION.pdf","http://www.domain.com/ArchivosCargados/2016/Estructura-RELGION.pdf","http://www.domain.com/ArchivosCargados/2016/PRIMERO-RELIGION.pdf","http://www.domain.com/ArchivosCargados/2016/RESPUESTAS-EUCARISTIA.pdf","http://www.domain.com/ArchivosCargados/2016/respuestas-misa.pdf","http://www.domain.com/ArchivosCargados/2016/Estructura-general-grado-primero-2016.pdf","http://www.domain.com/ArchivosCargados/2016/VESTUARIO-CLASE-EXPRESION-CORPORAL-2016.pdf","http://www.domain.com/ArchivosCargados/2016/RECOMENDACIONES-GENERALES-2016.pdf","http://www.domain.com/ArchivosCargados/2016/TEMAS-LOGRO-INDICADORES-PERIODO.pdf","http://www.domain.com/ArchivosCargados/2016/ENGLISH-USED-IN-CLASS.pdf","http://www.domain.com/ArchivosCargados/2016/lc-1.pdf","http://www.domain.com/ArchivosCargados/2016/Temas-logros.pdf","http://www.domain.com/ArchivosCargados/2016/Taller1-16.pdf","http://www.domain.com/ArchivosCargados/2016/PROGRAMA-PLATAFORMA.pdf","http://www.domain.com/ArchivosCargados/2016/first-grade.pdf"]}],"cookies":["ASP.NET_SessionId=\"0vy5tp45alrfik55q3bs24mr\";Path=\"/\";Domain=\"www.domain.com\";Port=\"80\""],"connectorVersionGuid":"e35c3b39-301e-4474-b75e-5473963b1852","connectorGuid":"b0fe3dd7-fd92-472b-b197-14d86f91c5fb","pageUrl":"http://www.domain.com/principal.aspx?tbindex=3&tab_codigo=33","outputProperties":[{"name":"actividades","type":"URL"}]}
```

Basicly, i have three objects: actividades, actividades/_text and actividades/_source. I want to create a final json file that have pair actividades and actividades/_text, in the same order that appear in file, i mean, for example:

```
"Ciencias Naturales Logro y Autoevaluación":"http://www.domain.com/ArchivosCargados/2016/CUADRO-PRIMER-BIMESTRE-2016-PRIMERO.pdf"
```

I want to do this using the linux terminal and doesn't matter if i must install some utility. I tried with jq without success:

```
jq '.actividades + .actividades/_text' test.json
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is the `transpose` filter.  The following:

```
.results[0] | [ ."actividades/_text", .actividades ] | transpose
```

produces pairs such as:

```
[
  "Ciencias Naturales Logro y Autoevaluación",
  "http://www.domain.com/ArchivosCargados/2016/CUADRO-PRIMER-BIMESTRE-2016-PRIMERO.pdf"
]
```

To combine these pairs into a single object, tack on:

```
| map({ (.[0]):.[1]} ) | add
```

To produce the output in the form "X":"Y" as you also indicated you want, you could use the following invocation:

```
jq -r  '.results[0]
| [ ."actividades/_text", .actividades ]
| transpose[]
| "\"\(.[0])\":\"\(.[1])\"" '
```

With your input, this last produces:

```
"Ciencias Naturales Logro y Autoevaluación":"http://www.domain.com/ArchivosCargados/2016/CUADRO-PRIMER-BIMESTRE-2016-PRIMERO.pdf"
"Ciencias Naturales Seres Vivos - Objetos Inertes":"http://www.domain.com/ArchivosCargados/2016/Hojita-Seres-Vivos.pdf"
....
....
```

Comment: Thanks @peak, very clever.
I am under OSX and tried with:
`jq -nr  '.results[0] | [ ."actividades/_text", .actividades ] | transpose[] | "\"\(.[0])\":\"\(.[1])\"" ' test.json `
and nothing happened. Thanks again!

Comment: i'm using jq 1.5 under OSX.